# Laravel Validation - Check Active Duplicate Emails

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

The table structure:

```
users: id  - email - active
```

I want check duplicated email only when `active` is 0.

For all emails,I do this:

```
'email' => 'required|unique:users|email',
```

Is it possible to define a condition in the validation?

Comment: I bet my google search took less time that you took to ask the question :)

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/validation-problem-on-edit-with-duplicated-email-addresses-unique-values-required

Comment: @RiggsFolly I wrote the answer of that page here myself. I want more. please read the question.

Comment: You can put validation rules into array and add them dynamically into `validation` method. Add condition like `if user which you are trying to edit is active` then push that `email => 'required|unique:users|email'` rule.

Answer (score 6):

What about using validator closure ?

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $this->validate($request, [
       'email' => [
           'required',
           'email',
           function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
               if (Users::whereEmail($value)->whereActive(0)->count() > 0) {
                   $fail($attribute.' is already used.');
               }
           },
       ]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `unique` rule has the following parameters:

> table[,column[,ignore value[,ignore column[,where column,where value]...]]]

So something like this will work without the overhead of a closure or other custom rule. (I use the array format because it's easier to read, friendlier for VCS, and Laravel just splits the string anyway.)

```
'email' => [
   'required',
   'email',
   'unique:users,email,null,null,active,0',
],
```

I set the ignore column and value to `null` as nothing was getting ignored in your original question. However, if you're doing this validation on update as well as create, you'll want to ignore the ID of the user you're updating.